# Reload plugin in sbt

Tags: sbt

How do I make sbt 0.11.3 use a new snapshot version of a plugin?

```
reload plugins
```

doesn't work.

```
reload plugins
clean
update
```

doesn't work.

Deleting the metadata files for the plugin in the ivy cache and restarting sbt doesn't work.

Comment: If you have to `clean` in 0.12.1 and later, it is probably a bug.  See http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Dependency-Management-Flow.html.  (Doesn't help you for 0.11.3 of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake. The plugin wasn't being reloaded because the new snapshot hadn't been published for the version of sbt that I was using.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699096/sbt-fetching-git-plugin related question, would you mind taking a look?

Answer (score 8):

```
sbt ";reload plugins ;update ;reload return"
```

Comment: Please add text to explain what you are doing here.