# sbt 0.11.3: getting latest version of a git plugin

Tags: scala, version-control, sbt

I've a multi-project structure which builds with sbt 0.11.3. I wanted to centralize my dependency versions, project versions, artifacts, shell prompt stuff and such. It would be really helpful for my plans on release management and version control. So I've created a plugin and put my global configurations there. My projects read it from github and build it as a plugin. Everything is lovely.

> ./project/project/Build.scala

```
import sbt._

object PluginDef extends Build {
    override lazy val projects = Seq(root)
    lazy val root = Project("plugins", file(".")) dependsOn(versionPlugin)
    lazy val versionPlugin = uri("git://github.com/config.git") //changed the uri here
}
```

So sbt fetches the plugins latest version if it haven't been already. Caches that version in *~/.sbt/staging/somehashcode*. But I couldn't make it update the project when there are changes in plugin project. I manually go and update it whenever needed. Sadly, in a 20 man team its causing some problems.

How can we make it check for plugin updates?

Comment: You mention that offline is false. You also mention that offline is true. Is the problem only for those developers that have offline set to true? Also you mention a lot *"my"*. You also mention 20 other developers. Is there consensus in the team on using your plugin?

Comment: i have fixed that offline part to true. but on a second look, i've realized that this mention is misleading. removing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but the following might work.

#### refreshing plugin

1. update to sbt 0.12.1, which fixes `update`
2. then from sbt shell:

   ```
   > reload plugins
   > update
   > reload return
   ```

#### specifying a particular tree

It may be helpful to fix the source dependency to a particular point in time for some situations. If so you can add commit hash or tag as `"git://github.com/config.git#hash"`.

Comment: moving to 0.12.1 is though stuff. I'd love to do that but we're in a "tight schedule"(as always). Still, I'll suggest that to my superiors. About the commit hash, getting the last commit id of our config project and checking it out as the plugin is a cool idea.

Comment: or straight from the shell
sbt ";reload plugins ;update ;reload return" ; sbt clean update compile